# При выборе combobox multibinding, убрать название столбцов List?

Tags: c#, wpf

Сам XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="350" Height="auto" IsEditable="True"
                          PreviewTextInput="comboBox_PreviewTextInput"  ToolTip="Введите первые 3 буквы фамилии"   Padding="5,5,5,5" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChaned"
                         >                
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2} {3} {4:dd.MM.yyyy}">
                                        <Binding Path="id"/>
                                        <Binding Path="fam"/>
                                        <Binding Path="name"/>
                                        <Binding Path="parent"/>
                                        <Binding Path="DOB"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

[image: Вот не правильно отображается]

Так заполняется List для combobox

```
 var result = db.Athletes
                .AsEnumerable()                  
                .Where(c => c.fam.ToLower().StartsWith(comboBox.Text.ToString()))
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    c.id,
                    c.fam,
                    c.name,
                    c.parent,                        
                    c.DOB              
                }
                )                    
                .Take(20)
                .ToList()
                ;            
                comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                comboBox.ItemsSource = result;
```

Это получает combobox [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас, похоже, не применяется `Template`. Покажите больше кода (и ваш `DataContext`)

Comment: А что у вас в DataContext'е?

Comment: Подтверждаю, у меня ваш код работает правильно. Попробуйте то же самое на новом проекте.

Comment: Кстати, а нет ли у вас глобальных стилей или чего-нибудь подобного?

Comment: Нет ничего такого нет, выводится строка List при выборе. Не знаю как ее разобрать чтобы было без этого {id =15, fam="",name итд} при селекте

Comment: Окей, попробуйте это на новом проекте: http://pastebin.com/R5YpCMBt, http://pastebin.com/3Y4Up0Pz

Answer (score 1):

У меня по вашему коду все выводится хорошо и правильно.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="25">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2} {3:dd.MM.yyyy}">
                                <Binding Path="fam" />
                                <Binding Path="name" />
                                <Binding Path="parent" />
                                <Binding Path="DOB" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

использую вот так.

Comment: При выборе из списка получается вот так { fam = Семенов, name = Семен, parent = Семенович, DOB = 17.06.2016 15:41:41 }, а хочется Семенов Семен 17.06.2016

Comment: У меня выводится как и "хочется". Точно итем темплейт у вас внутри комбо-бокса? xaml весь скопируйте.